# Choosing the right SQL database connection method

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, remote-access

I have a Windows POS application with remote SQL database.
What is the best way to connect my application to database ?

I'm thinking of connecting with one of these methods

- port foreword ( currently using this methods. but it fails to connect sometimes, then I have to restart SQL server to get it connected again or wait for long )
- VPN access
- Install local SQL server and use replication to main server ( but I cannot lock database from unauthorized access as SQL local server and POS application running on the same system )

Please suggest me an option or if there any better option

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: VPN and only allowing local access sounds like the securest way to me. A few words about your requirements would be good though.

Comment: I have two POS system installed at two locations. So each shop have only one system available and POS is installed in it. It will be great if I can store data locally and then update with main server with database replication ( but I don't want anyone to copy an unlocked database )

Comment: And if I'm using VPN , I don't want VPN users to access any data on the server other than just Database connectivity. ( I fear I'll expose my sever with VPN as I cannot control what client do with their machin)

Comment: If you have connectivity issues then you need to implement some kind of queuing / retry functionality. With regards to securing your database, just make sure that the users do not have a login to the database